# Is it possible to set proxy settings in a Safari Extension?

Tags: proxy, safari

As Apple introduce extension support in Safari 5, I want to make an extension that manage proxy settings directly in the browser (like [AutoProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11009/) for Firefox or [Proxy Switchy](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj) for Chrome).

I skimmed the [source code of Proxy Switchy](http://code.google.com/p/switchy/). It is mainly written in Javascript/HTML, but uses an external binary bundle to do proxy switching. Is this scheme doable in Safari extension? If not, is there other way to manage proxy settings in the extension?

Comment: You might not be able to do this in a cross-platform manner, as the proxy settings are managed by the OS in OS X (I don't know about windows)

Comment: @pkaeding Yes, I'm aware of that. I just want to focus on Mac for now.

Answer (score 6):

I am having exactly same question although it is almost 2016 already and I am using Safari 9.0.2. It seems that Apple does not provide such an API for defining browser-specific proxy in extensions as Google does for Chrome. So I guess one would have to deal with system-wide proxy settings, that is to find solutions for setting up app-specific proxy.

Answer (score -1):

(this the the link, not advertising) http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-226884

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18370/why-isnt-my-auto-proxy-setting-working-for-safari-5-1-in-lion

(answer from techrepublic and apple.stackexchange it's not advertising)

I think they say you can

Comment: Please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Actually the easiest way is to use Apple's concept of 'Location'. In the Apple Menu, choose Location > Network Preferences ...

Most likely your current location is set as 'Automatic'. Choose "Edit Locations ..." in the selection menu, and add additional Proxy Locations. For each Location you can setup different proxy settings, which you can switch directly from the apple menu. Just make sure you edit the correct Network Interface on which you want to apply the proxy settings (if you are connected through LAN, but you set the proxy only on Wifi - it wouldn't work).

The Proxy Settings are under the [Advanced ...] button [proxies] tab. Enable and modify the proxies as you need.

Make sure that your Safari browser - or any browser you will be using - is set to use the "System Proxy Settings" ... and not it's own override. Safari always links back to the System Network Settings.

After considering this - would we still need a plugin doing essentially the same?

Comment: @igor - you are right - It is system-wide, so depending on what you need, might be useless or exactly what you need. I use chrome with a plugin for those cases where I need to run a web site through a ssh tunnel etc.

Comment: yep but the main point of doing it with browser extension is that it allows more flexibility by having rules which can select different proxy servers per request depending on url

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible to set proxy setting in safari. Please follow below steps.

1.) Open Safari if it is not already open. 
2.) Choose Safari > Preferences, and then click Advanced. 
3.) Click Change Settings.

The Network pane of System Preferences opens.
Use the information you got from your network administrator to change the proxy settings. 
Click OK.